# How to get Controller list in page java script

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

```
Calculator__c objCalculator  = [Select id, name, (select id,
fee_amount__c, cost_Amount__c, Type__c, from
Non_Labor_Cost_Details__r) From Calculator__c p where id =: PId];
```

When I try to use this object in Javascript like this:

```
{!objPricingCalculator.Non_Labor_Cost_Details__r}
```

It returns only list of Ids (comma separated). It's not returning
`fee_amount__c`, `cost_Amount__c` and `Type__c` values.

Is there any way through which I can also extract `fee_amount__c`, `cost_Amount__c` and `Type__c` along with `Id`.

I don't want to use Javascript Remoting as I will have to change code flow for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Apex class

```
 public class sample{

 public Account gethello(){

      Account acc=[Select Id,(Select id,Name from Contacts) from Account where Id =acc.id];
     return acc;

   }
}
```

Visualforce code with Javascript

```
<apex:page controller="sample">

<script>

<apex:repeat var="a" value="{!hello.Contacts}">
   alert('hello'+'{!a.Name}');
 </apex:repeat>

 </script>

 </apex:page>
```

This is the starting point.Now you can declare your own function in javascript something like this in script

```
function Contact(){
      /* Note the field names are case-sensitive! */
      this.Id = null; /* set a value here if you need to update or delete */
      this.Name = null;
  }
```

After this you can use push function of javascript to form an object array using some samples from below URL.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp